# Trouble running imported c++ program with Eclipse. Can run in debug mode, but cannot run directly

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have a large c++ Eclipse project that I have just imported into Eclipse on a different computer.  I can build the project (using Cygwin GCC toolchain), and can run in debug mode, but cannot run the executable directly from Eclipse after setting up a run configuration.  All that shows up in the console is the usual "nothing to be done for all" build message, followed by "terminated- program name."  No more information shows up in the console.

I should also mention that I can run the executable created when the program is compiled and built in eclipse, but only if I run it outside eclipse.

Any help would be much appreciated!  Please let me know if any other information would help.

Comment: Did you build the release binary too?, the one that is stored in the Release directory, it should we smaller than the debug binary

Comment: I don't seem to have a release directory or release binary.  But I should be able to run the debug binary right?

Comment: Well of course you can! Just go to Eclipse->Right click on your Project-> Run As -> Run Configurations -> New Launch Configuration -> Main Tab -> in the C/C++ Application dialog add the path and name of your debug binary and then run.

Comment: That's what doesn't seem to be working.  It's the strangest thing because I can run the binary outside of eclipse, but I can't run it within Eclipse using the process you just laid out.

Comment: If I go into my eclipse, then build a release version (Project Properties -> Paths and Symbols -> Manage Configurations -> Release -> Set Active) it wont run either because I am using libraries that need to be set in LD_Library_path

Comment: I found a solution on eclipse.org:

Comment: 1 Goto Project->Properties->Run/Debug Settings, choose the .exe file and press "Edit"

2 In the "Environment" tag, press "New", set it as: 
"Name:PATH"
"Value:C:\MinGW\bin"